# Can I tell MSVC compiler not to use a certain register?

Tags: c, visual-c++

Is there a way to tell the MSVC compiler not to modify a certain register for a brief period of time? Like, inside a small loop, to tell it not to use the ebx register (it could use any of the other registers). Pushing and popping the register does not work in this case because MSVC automatically rearranges the code to modify the register after I pop it back - it must see some kind of an optimization to be done there.

Comment: sounds like an XY problem.  Whatever you think you need this register for can probably be accomplished more straightforwardly without it.

Comment: Presumably you have `for() loop in C {assembly code}` If you store `ebx` in a local variable and then reload it, that would have the same effect as stacking it, and hey ho that's on the stack too!

Comment: The compiler, or the output executable?

Comment: Either way, if you make a syscall or get hardware-interrupted, ebx is gonna change, (and change back).  Wot yer doin' ?

Comment: @MartinJames I don't understand either of your last 2 comments. Please explain. There isn't a way to tell the processor not to use `ebx` apart from not compiling/assembling its use, and why should application code be concerned about what happens to `ebx` during interrupts?

Comment: @WeatherVane 'Can I tell MSVC compiler not to use a certain register?' was your title.  I'm sure the compiler uses all the general-purpose register set, including ebx.  As for the output executable, the reason you want to avoid using ebx is not known, so we don't know whether you have an interrupt-handler, driver, kernel or user-space problem with ebx.  You don't say anything about 'applications' in your question.  Your question was vague, so expect vague comments/answers.

Comment: @MartinJames sorry you misunderstood me. I am not the OP, but why should the coder be concerned with what happens to `ebx` during a hardware interrupt at *any* level of programming?

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you can instruct the compiler not to use ebx. However, it sounds like ebx is set to some value somewhere in your program (maybe as a part of the function return value of a function you called), and you want this value in ebx available at some other point in your program, maybe before another function you want to call. Then the following might be a possibility:

```
myFuncA(...);  // returns something in ebx
__asm push ebx
....
.... // C code
....
__asm pop ebx
myFuncB();   // wants something in ebx
```

Note: myFuncB() may not have parameters, otherwise the compiler can use ebx for getting and pushing the parameters; if it has parameters, you may have to code the whole function call in asm.